Models with plastic residues on edges
I just received a new 3D printer from Bambu Lab (A1 to be exact) and I'm a complete newbie to 3D printing. I'm currently doing a couple test prints using what's already available on the Bambu community. While going through my second model print, I noticed plastic residue gets collected on one side of the inner walls (Seems to be the seem area marked in white of my screenshot). I'm attaching a few images and photos of my model for reference.

Would anyone know what the problem might be and how to troubleshoot?

This is the result when you have an overpressure in the nozzle while moving to a start of layer printing. Also known as oozing.
This implies that your printer is not well calibrated. Oozing occurrs when the filament has not been retracted enough (eleviating the pressure in the nozzle) on moving or the printing temperature is too high. When arriving at the layer (start) position, any oozed out material gets stuck on your print, creating ugly blobs. You see in the slicer image the white areas, these are start position after a move and coincide with the defects in your print.
You could print some retraction test towers to fine-tune the oozing of your printer.

Thank you for your reply. I did notice some filament oozing out before a layer starts.
I'm recalibrating as I'm writing this comment. If the problem continues, how can I use the retraction tower to improve my prints? What parameters do I need to tweak to increase retraction?

E.g. print a retraction calibration print and vary retraction length for each new cylinder. How to do that, search the site please. It involves editing G-code. Other parameters to look for is the retraction speed and filament temperature; you might also want to increase traveling speed. I'll see if I can make a Q and A on this next week.
